# Trying to understand and solve ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in a Reactive Form

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm relatively new to Angular and specially Reactive Forms, so I'm a bit lost as to why I'm getting the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` in a simple form.

[Please refer to this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkytux)

I understand the idea of the exception, but not what I'm doing wrong to cause it, and how to solve this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Specifically `this.formGroup.reset();` in `loadCurrentClient()` is causing this for your information.

Comment: Sometimes it's to do with the [template hierarchy](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18004#issuecomment-328806479)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify **ClientGeneralComponent**'s `ngAfterViewInit()` like this:

`import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';`

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {  }


ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadCurrentClient();

     this.clientUpdateSubscription = this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(newVal => {
        this.updateClient();
     });
     this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v22xbb)

To understand in depth read this [article](https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/)

Comment: All authors (including in link below) recommend not to use such hacks but to redesign logic instead.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be to update `ngAfterViewInit` to put in in separate task:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  Promise.resolve(null).then(() => {
    this.loadCurrentClient();
    this.clientUpdateSubscription = this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(newVal => {
      this.updateClient();
    });
  });
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmhd9z?file=src/app/client-general.component.ts

But in ideal case it is better to change design. For example you could get rid of separate `currentClient` and form. Leave only form and do everything you need with it's values in method `ngSubmit()`.

Comment: Interesting solution. Why does putting the code inside the Promise block solve the problem?

Comment: The code in stackblitz is only part of the view.The reason I have a currentClient object is because the view is composed of multiple child components, where each allows editing different properties of the Client object. So I use the currentClient to maintain this data while switching between them, before submitting.

Comment: @DanielMoisésGonzalezClua With promise we send code execution to the next microtask and it is being executed in the next Angular check cycle. It is kind of more elegant way of setTimeout(() => {...}, 0)